# Ajax call with cordova whitelist error

Tags: ajax, cordova, whitelist

I've seen many posts about implementing cordova whitelist plugin but after a full week of testing i still haven't spotted what's my mistake.

This ajax call throws these alerts:

xhr {"readystate":0,"status":0,"statustext":"error"}.

status "error"

error ""

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/my_file.php',
    data: {type: 'test', code: '11'},
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('done '+JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('xhr '+JSON.stringify(xhr));
            alert('status'+JSON.stringify(status));
            alert('error '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

I updated my phonegap build app with the new cordova whitelist implementation adding this to the meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.example.com; connect-src 'self' http://www.example.com">
```

this to the config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

and this in the js before ajax calls:

```
$.support.cors=true;
```

I'm using all the wildcards at the moment for the testing, i'll change later. This is the server php file i'm calling:

```
<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = json_encode(array($_GET));

echo $data;

?>
```

Phonegap build version cli-5.2.0
Android 4.1.1
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Both of your codes work just fine. Make sure your urls are correct, since that could be an issue. Can you try `alert(error);` to see what error you are actualy getting

Comment: the exact same requests work if called in a browser so it can't be the URL and it should be something about the cordova whitelist i guess. i edit the post to include the error and clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `config.xml`

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: i tried but still getting same error, did you wrote <access origin="*"/> twice on purpose ?